# Google App Engine - Endpoints Failure

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy a gae project with endpoints but it's giving me errors that's should be happening.

I Don't Think there is anything wrong with my code but i keep getting this  error when trying to deploy:

```
There is a /_ah/spi handler configured, but no Google Cloud Endpoints service was found in the app
```

my app.yaml :

```
application: app-id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

# --- Handlers

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app
  secure: always

- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js

- url: /img
  static_dir: static/img

- url: /css
  static_dir: static/bootstrap/css

- url: /fonts
  static_dir: static/fonts

- url: /partials
  static_dir: static/partials



- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: game.api
  secure: always


# --- Libraries

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"

- name: pycrypto
  version: latest

- name: endpoints
  version: latest

- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

and my game.py :

```
from datetime import datetime

import endpoints
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import remote

from google.appengine.api import memcache
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

# --- Setup Code

WEB_CLIENT_ID = 'app-id'

# --- Classes

class Hello(messages.Message):
    """String that stores a message."""
    greeting = messages.StringField(1)

class TestOne(messages.Message):
    ''' TestOne message '''
    msg = messages.StringField(1)

# --- API & Endpoints

@endpoints.api(name='whoamigame', version='v1')
class WhoAmIGameApi(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, TestOne, path='testone', http_method='GET', name='testonemethod')
    def testOneM(self, req):
        testOneMsgReturn = TestOne(msg='Test One...')
        return testOneMsgReturn



# --- API

api = endpoints.api_server([WhoAmIGameApi])
```

Every time i try to deploy it, the endpoints fail. i'm not sure how to fix this issue. the code and syntax is perfect to me. everything is defined. the sdk fails every time.

Comment: where game.py file exists?

Comment: in the same root directory ass the app.yaml